# Undefined offset: 1 Failed to prepare SQL: INSERT INTO

Tags: php, mysql, yii2, openserver

Помогите,пожалуйста,разобраться,целый день не могу понять ошибки. Есть проект. Его одинаковые версии лежать локально на OpenServer и на тестовом сервере. Так вот локально все работает, а на тестовом выдает ошибку при INSERT, может кто сталкивался и подскажет где копать? спасибо. скрины версий софта на сервере прилагаю.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Сама ошибка текстом**

```
Database Exception – yii\db\Exception
Undefined offset: 1
Failed to prepare SQL: INSERT INTO `seminars`.`bg_seminar` (`seminar_tema`, `seminar_subject`, `seminar_place`, `seminar_otdel`, `seminar_db`, `seminar_de`, `seminar_belgiss`, `seminar_gosstandart`) VALUES (:qp0, :qp1, :qp2, :qp3, :qp4, :qp5, :qp6, :qp7)
↵
Caused by: yii\base\ErrorException
```

```
 in /work/web/dseminar/dev/www/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Command.php at line 227


            $pdo = $this->db->getMasterPdo();
        }

        try {
            $this->pdoStatement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $this->bindPendingParams();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $message = $e->getMessage() . "\nFailed to prepare SQL: $sql";
            $errorInfo = $e instanceof \PDOException ? $e->errorInfo : null;
            throw new Exception($message, $errorInfo, (int) $e->getCode(), $e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Cancels the execution of the SQL statement.
     * This method mainly sets [[pdoStatement]] to be null.
     */
    public function cancel()
    {

2. in /work/web/dseminar/dev/www/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Command.php at line 775 – yii\db\Command::prepare(false)
3. in /work/web/dseminar/dev/www/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Schema.php at line 448 – yii\db\Command::execute()
4. in /work/web/dseminar/dev/www/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/ActiveRecord.php at line 454 – yii\db\Schema::insert('seminars.bg_seminar', ['seminar_tema' => 'Тест2', 'seminar_subject' => '2', 'seminar_place' => 'ывываыва', 'seminar_otdel' => ['2'], ...])
5. in /work/web/dseminar/dev/www/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/ActiveRecord.php at line 424 – yii\db\ActiveRecord::insertInternal(null)
6. in /work/web/dseminar/dev/www/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/BaseActiveRecord.php at line 593 – yii\db\ActiveRecord::insert(true, null)
7. in /work/web/dseminar/dev/www/controllers/SeminarsController.php at line 93 – yii\db\BaseActiveRecord::save()


                date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime(Main::translateDate(
                Yii::$app->request->post('Bg_seminar')['seminar_db'])));
            $model->seminar_de = 
                date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime(Main::translateDate(
                Yii::$app->request->post('Bg_seminar')['seminar_de'])));

            $model->save();

            SeminarCreateForm::saveTags($model);

            $ObjFiles->seminar_files = UploadedFile::getInstances($ObjFiles, 'seminar_files');
            if($ObjFiles->seminar_files) {


8. app\controllers\SeminarsController::actionCreate()
9. in /work/web/dseminar/dev/www/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/InlineAction.php at line 55 – call_user_func_array([app\controllers\SeminarsController, 'actionCreate'], [])
10. in /work/web/dseminar/dev/www/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php at line 151 – yii\base\InlineAction::runWithParams([])
11. in /work/web/dseminar/dev/www/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php at line 455 – yii\base\Controller::runAction('create', [])
12. in /work/web/dseminar/dev/www/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Application.php at line 84 – yii\base\Module::runAction('seminars/create', [])
13. in /work/web/dseminar/dev/www/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php at line 375 – yii\web\Application::handleRequest(yii\web\Request)
14. in /work/web/dseminar/dev/www/htdocs/index.php at line 28 – yii\base\Application::run()



require(__DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');

$config = require(__DIR__ . '/../config/web.php');

(new yii\web\Application($config))->run();
```

Comment: Код со скриншота приведите текстом. Я не вижу, что там у вас написано

Comment: и **полный** текст ошибки, а не первую половину. И тоже **текстом**

Comment: добавил и то и то под скринами

Comment: На тестовом сервере в таблице bg_seminar отсутствуют какие-то поля

Comment: я облизал эту таблицу,все на месте.там напрямую написал этот запрос в мускуле


`INSERT INTO seminars.bg_seminar (seminar_tema, seminar_subject, seminar_place, seminar_otdel,
  seminar_db, seminar_de, seminar_belgiss, seminar_gosstandart) VALUES ( :qp0, :qp1, :qp2, :qp3, :qp4, :qp5, :qp6, :qp7)`

и он работает и добавляет. и c локального опенсервера норм отрабатывает в проекте,а вот в индентичном проекте на сервере - нет. тут какой-то конфликт,но я не могу понять какой :(

Comment: Может быть что-то похожее https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42287089/undefined-offset-1-in-my-yii2-site. Проверьте что в полях модели нет массивов

Comment: Почему у вас на сервере версия php стоит 5.3? Yii минимум нужен php 5.4

Comment: Рекомендую все обновить. Если на локалке нет ошибки, а на проде есть, значит кодовая база различается.

Comment: `'seminar_otdel' => ['2']` - не смущает наличие массива?

Comment: для  pa3py6aka phpinfo выводит что версия PHP Version 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.26  Apache 2.0 Handler

Comment: для fedornabilkin - так а как оно может отличаться,если под контролем версий? да и я уже все возможные файлы и так скопипастил,чтобы исключить различие. завтра может попробуй туда скопировать еще раз,но сомневаюсь что поможет

Comment: для  Anton Shchyrov убрал из формы 'seminar_otdel' , заработало,значит дело в этом. спасибо!! но,честно,во первых я не понимаю почему,а во 2 локально же зашло

Comment: возможно локально ворнинги отключены

Comment: @AlexandrZalamay так поставьте php минимум 5.4. Или 5.5, как на локалке. Окружение везде желательно иметь одинаковое

Comment: @pa3py6aka перенес на сервер PHP Version 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.29 , ничего не поменялось, появилась даже еще проблема с non-static методами,но ее решил.

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov спасибо большое, ваше замечание было верным

Comment: @AlexandrZalamay странно всё же почему у вас разные ошибки на сервере и на локалке

Answer (score 0):

Если возникает такая ошибка (в запросе встречается `:qp0`) или подобная, то первым делом надо проверить входные параметры. Они должны быть скалярами.

Такой запрос:

```
$task = static::find()
    ->where([
        'orderId' => $orderId,
        'taskTypeId' => $taskTypeId,
    ])
    ->andWhere(['!=', 'taskStatus', [TaskStatus::FINISHED]])
    ->one();
```

Вызывает такую ошибку:

```
[yii\db\Exception] Undefined offset: 1
Failed to prepare SQL: SELECT * FROM "task" WHERE (("orderId"=:qp0) AND 
("taskTypeId"=:qp1)) AND ("taskStatus" != :qp2)
```

В коде достаточно сложно определить, что `TaskStatus::FINISHED` передается не скалярным значением, а массивом. Ошибка в `[TaskStatus::FINISHED]`